# Sleep() doesn't work in winapi32?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++-2008

I'm still a beginner in programming GUI using c++ winapi32, and I found something strange.
Here's a part of my code:

```
        InvalidateRect(hwnd,&rect, true);
        //Sleep(delay);
        MessageBox(hwnd, "Blahblah!", "blahblah",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        InvalidateRect(hwnd,&rect, true);
        //Sleep(delay);
        MessageBox(hwnd, "Blahblah!", "blahblah",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

I use Invalidaterect to repaint a part of my windows, and what I'm trying to do is to repaint the windows every 1 second or so to make the changes apparent to the user's eyes. The strange part is that Sleep seems to not affect my windows if it's not followed by MessageBox command, while in fact I dont want to have any MessageBox command for every repainting because it's too disturbing.

I've tried 1000,2000, even 10000 for the delay.
The windoes did freeze with the sleep, but the apparent repainting is only done 1x in the last Sleep command...

This code is a part of, say, void A(). And void A() is called by void B().

```
       //Message loop
       if(turn == 0)
       {
       B();
       }
```

Is there any alternative that I can do to fix this problem?

Oh yeah, I use MS Visual C++ 2008 Express by the way

Thanks in advance for any help regarding this matter :)

Comment: What value of `delay` did you try?

Comment: 1000, 2000, even 10000 doesn't make any effect if there's no MessageBox command... What i mean by 'no effect' is: Suppose there're 3 repaint command followed by 3 sleep command for each of it, the windows just freeze for 3x delay, and the repaint only done 1x in the last....but if I also add MessageBox command for every Sleep command, It's apparent that the windows did really repainting 3 times...any help?

Comment: This is *really* fundamental in Windows GUI programming.  Paints don't occur until you pump the message loop.  Put the keyboard away and read a book.

Comment: Where did you put this code? If it is in a handler that it is *indirectly* executed by window repaint, it may enter in a loop in which new repaint events are stored each time a redraw is started.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I did use message loop. The repainting did occur, but it's only done 1x apparently in the last sleep command, though I called it 2 times

Comment: @Diego Sevilla: In the message loop, I called void B(), and void B() called void A(), and this code is part of void A()

Comment: The message loop doesn't run when you call Sleep! Sleep is the correct solution to a vanishingly small number of problems. This is not one of those problems. Take the sage advice of Hans. Get hold of Petzold's book and read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important thing is, that `InvalidateRect` doesn't draw anything. It only schedules the window content to be drawn (enqueues a `WM_PAINT` message into the message queue). The actual drawing doesn't happen until you return to the message loop and the window actually gets to process the paint message. So after the last Sleep/MessageBox you finally return from your function to arrive at the message loop again and in the message loop you finally get the `WM_PAINT` message that represents the actual paint event and process this message to redraw the window's content.

Comment: I see, but when I put Sleep in the first line WM_PAINT case, why does the program seems to behave the same? I mean, I can only see the last repainting though It's called countless times. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @zia The `InvalidateRect` only schedules the window to be painted (tells Win32, that this window's content is invalid). Actually the paint event has a very low priority to not spam redraw events when the window should do more important things. And Win32 is intelligent enough to only put a single paint message into the message queue. So when you call `InvalidateRect` and already have a `WM_PAINT` in the message queue, Win32 merges this request with the previous one (merges the rects into a possibly larger rect containing both), so you always have only one paint event, until you process it.